# How do I prevent accidentally building X as a dependency when installing a port?

Tags: port, xorg, freebsd, headless

I'm running FreeBSD in a small VM image, and I want to keep it headless. Is there an easy flag to set somewhere to prevent installing X as a dependency, or do I just need to rely on eternal vigilance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2004-July/007813.html), you should set `WITHOUT_X11=yes` in `/etc/make.conf`.